# how to solve MMV sparse representation with CVX

Tags: matlab, optimization, sparse-matrix, cvx

I want to solve multiple measurement vector (MMV) sparse representation problem with CVX toolbox. I have a N*L matrix X. matrix X have only a few nonzero rows. I have system of equations Y=A*X. Y is M*L matrix of measurements (M

min Relax(X)
subject to Y=A*X

Realx(.) is a function that applies norm 1 to the vector t. (N*1)vector t consists of the norm 2 of each rows of matrix X. i.e. Relax(X)= norm_1(t) and t(i)=norm_2(X(i,:))

I can’t transform my objective function into a language that CVX can understand and solve.
Please tell me how I should change the problem objective and constraints that CVX could solve it.

Answer (score 0):

'norms' is the cvx command you're looking for. Suppose sigma is some known parameter that allows Y to be only approximately equal to A*X (e.g. I tried it with sigma=10e-6). Then you could use this code:

```
cvx_begin separable

    variable X(n,n)
    minimize( norms(X,2,1) )
    subject to
       norm(Y - A*X,2)<= 10*sigma

cvx_end
```

Comment: thank you Laura, but it seems the command "norms" only works for square matrices. my unknown matrix is M*L

Answer (score 0):

```
cvx_begin separable

variable Sp(N,m) complex;% there are m samples
minimize( sum(norms(Sp.',2)) );
subject to
A*Sp==y;
%     norm(y - A*Sp,2)<= 1e-8;

cvx_end
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**